# AngularJS Doesn't hold value

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

i'm trying to set a value to a angular service on a controller and getting it from another one, but the service doesn't hold the value.

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('Test', []);

app.service('editorPost', function() {

    this.ID = -1;

    this.setID = function(ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    };

    this.getID = function() {
        return this.ID;
    };
});
```

First controller

```
app.controller('DashboardController', ['$scope','editorPost',
function ($scope, editorPost) {
        $scope.loadEditor = function(link)
        {
            editorPost.setID(link.post.ID);
            // Displays the correct ID, obtained from the <a> clicked.
            console.log(editorPost.getID());
        };

    }]);
```

The loadEditor function gets called like this:

```
<a href="/editor/editor.html" ng-click="loadEditor(this)">{{ post.webStory }}</a>
```

After console.logging the value, it would redirect to the editor.html and display the default ID value from the service.

Second controller (the one from editor/editor.html):

```
app.controller('EditorController', ['$scope','editorPost',
    function ($scope,editorPost)
{
    $scope.globals = globals;
    //Displays the default value, -1.
    console.log(editorPost.getID());
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're inside a method in your service, this refers to that method, not the service. Change your service to look like this:

```
app.service('editorPost', function() {

    var service = this;
    service.ID = -1;

    service.setID = function(ID) {
        service.ID = ID;
    };

    service.getID = function() {
        return service.ID;
    };

    return service;
});
```

So actually, that's one issue. The second issue is that you're going to a new HTML page with your href. I'm guessing that you're reloading angular and your app there which re-instantiates the service and sets the id back to its default value. You really need to be using angular as a SPA in this scenario or else you'll need to pass the ID as a URL parameter and grab it from there.

Comment: Still holds the -1 value on the second controller.

Comment: Never used it, but can i redirect from one page to another within codepen?.

I'll try and put it up.

Comment: If you want, just add the html for the 2 pages in question to your question and I'll recreate it locally.

Comment: Don't know if this codepen makes sense, but there it is.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZGGVq?editors=1111

If what i want it's not possible, how could i pass the value via URL?

Comment: Yeah, it does. See the edit I added to my initial answer. That's the issue. The 2nd page reloads angular and recreates the service.

Comment: in that case you can use angular route "https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute" for avoid that behavior

Answer (score 1):

I will say that the best could be pass a function to the service like a callback, something like the following

**//EditorController**

```
editorPost.getID (function(data){
       console.log(data);
});
```

into the service instead of use the return you need something like the following

```
app.service('editorPost', function() {

    this.ID = -1;

    this.setID = function(ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    };

    this.getID = function(callback) {
        callback(this.ID);
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried what you said and the second controller still outputs the -1 value.